# Check if numbers are sequential according to another column?

Tags: python, pandas, logic

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
Numbers             Names
0                     A
1                     A
2                     B
3                     B
4                     C
5                     C
6                     C
8                     D
10                    D
```

And my numbers(integers) need to be sequential IF the value in the column "Names" is the same for both numbers: so for example, between 6 and 8 the numbers are not sequential but that is fine since the column "Names" changes from C to D. However, between 8 and 10 this is a problem since both rows have the same value "Names" but are not sequential.

I would like to do a code that returns the numbers missing that need to be added according to the logic explained above.

```
import itertools as it
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_excel("booki.xlsx")

c1 = df['Numbers'].copy()
c2 = df['Names'].copy()


for i in it.chain(range(1,len(c2)-1), range(1,len(c1)-1)):
    b = c2[i]
    c = c2[i+1]
    x = c1[i]
    n = c1[i+1]
    if c == b and n - x > 1:
        print(x+1)
```

It prints the numbers that are missing but two times, so for the data frame in the example it would print:

```
9
9
```

but I would like to print only:

```
9
```

Perhaps it's some failure in the logic?

Thank you

Comment: Can you add expected result?

Comment: I think the problem is ```itertools.chain```. why are you using it?

Comment: @VictorRuiz I adapted from a solution I found online, but basically because I need to use two for loops for the range and it.chain lets me specify two ranges (due to it being two columns that I am iterating through). But another solution would be preferred actually since it works well in Anaconda but not in IDLE

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`groupby('Names')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and then [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to get the differences between following elements within each group, then pick only the ones that don't have `-1` as a differnce, and print their following number.

try this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
Numbers             Names
0                     A
1                     A
2                     B
3                     B
4                     C
5                     C
6                     C
8                     D
10                    D"""), sep="\s+")

differences = df.groupby('Names', as_index=False).apply(lambda g: g['Numbers'] - g['Numbers'].shift(-1)).fillna(-1).reset_index()
missing_numbers = (df[differences != -1]['Numbers'].dropna()+1).tolist()
print(missing_numbers)
```

Output:

```
[9.0]
```

Comment: What's happened if there is a gap bigger than 1 ?

Comment: You mean if 10 was changed to 11? Output would still be just 9, seems like what OPs code is doing as well.

Comment: Right. I didn't understand it like this :-)

Comment: If the expected output is to print the entire gap, we can easily use the value of differences to so so.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure `itertools` is needed here. Here is one solution only using pandas methods.

1. Group the data according to `Names` column using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)
2. Select the [`min`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.min.html) and [`max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) from `Numbers` columns
3. Define an integer range from min to max
4. [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) this value with the sub dataframe
5. Filter according missing values using [`isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html)
6. Return the filtered df
7. Optional : reindex the columns for prettier output with [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

Here the code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Numbers": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 15],
                   "Names": ["A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D"]})

def select_missing(df):
    # Select min and max values
    min_ = df.Numbers.min()
    max_ = df.Numbers.max()
    # Create integer range
    serie = pd.DataFrame({"Numbers": [i for i in range(min_, max_ + 1)]})
    # Merge with df 
    m = serie.merge(df, on=['Numbers'], how='left')
    # Return rows not matching the equality
    return m[m.isna().any(axis=1)]


# Group the data per Names and apply "select_missing" function
out = df.groupby("Names").apply(select_missing)
print(out)
#          Numbers Names
# Names
# D     1        9   NaN
#       3       11   NaN
#       4       12   NaN
#       5       13   NaN
#       6       14   NaN

out = out[["Numbers"]].reset_index(level=0)
print(out)
#   Names  Numbers
# 1     D        9
# 3     D       11
# 4     D       12
# 5     D       13
# 6     D       14
```

Comment: thanks a lot! but i'm getting the error TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: Is there `float` in the `Numbers` columns ?

Comment: actually yes, for some reason pandas is importing my excel file Numbers columns as a float --> like the number 2200000109 becomes  2.200001e+09

Comment: Before processing, you can try to cast the column `numbers` to integer with: `df.Numbers = df.Numbers.astype(int)`. The notation `2.200001e+09` is the scientific notation. Have a read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation).